# mex compilation error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const mwSize *' to 'const int32_t *'

Tags: c++, matlab, compiler-errors, mex

I don't have experience with C/C++ syntax and I am facing the issue of adjusting this change of syntax. I am trying to generate the mex file for libvisio2. I have visual studio 2017 and matlab 2018a.

the complete error is

```
D:\Libraries\libviso2\matlab\matcherMex.cpp(101): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const mwSize *' to
'const int32_t *'
D:\Libraries\libviso2\matlab\matcherMex.cpp(101): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires
reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

where the lines in the file matcherMex.cpp are:

```
 99:   // get pointer to left image
100:    uint8_t* I1          = (uint8_t*)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
101:    const int32_t *dims1 = mxGetDimensions(prhs[1]);
102:    
103:    // transpose
104:    uint8_t* I1_         = transpose<uint8_t>(I1,dims1);
105:    int32_t  dims1_[]    = {dims1[1],dims1[0],dims1[1]};
```

Any help would be appreciated , Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that the return type of 'mxGetDimensions(prhs[1])' is 'const mwSize *' but you are trying to save it as an int.

Comment: `const int32_t *dims1 = mxGetDimensions(prhs[1]);` ... mxGetDimensions() returns a `const` pointer to `mwSize` (whatever that might be) and is incompatible with `int32_t`. There is not much else to say about it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments JakobL and  @Swordfish . 

However, when i  replace int32 with mwSize then i get this error in line 104
  error C2664: 'T *transpose<uint8_t>(T *,const int32_t *)': cannot
convert argument 2 from 'const mwSize *' to 'const int32_t *'
        with
        [
            T=uint8_t
        ]

The reconversion is confusing me here.

Comment: @ihti learn about C types. Sometimes you need to make auxiliary variables to pass information in a different type, they are very important. If transpose gets a `int32_t` but `mexGetDimensions` only returns `mwSize` its your job to make sure there is an intermediate step where the data changes type.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for the suggestion. I will obviously try to learn C programming for later. I have done most of my work with Matlab and I trying to compare results with an implementation  that was done in C and at the moment I have minimum understanding of the programming tricks with C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling, you need to pass the [`-compatibleArrayDims`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#btw17rw-1-option1optionN) to the `mex` function.

By default, MEX-files are compiled in a mode where array indices and sizes are stored in 64-bit integers (this is how MATLAB stores them natively). Back in the old days, presumably when your code was written, they were 32-bit integers. The given compiler flag will make MATLAB automatically convert the types of these variables for you (and hopefully throw an error if the array size is too large to fit in a 32-bit integer).