# How to solve C++ MEX-file compilation error in Matlab R2018b with Windows 10, 64 bit?

Tags: c++, matlab, compiler-errors

I try to compile a C++ MEX-file in Matlab R2018b, but an error was occurred after compiling `mex RegionGrowing_mex_modified.cpp` in the command window of Matlab. the error was:

[image]

So, I searched and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350219/mex-compilation-error-c2440-initializing-cannot-convert-from-const-mwsize), that after doing the suggestion, `mex -compatibleArrayDims RegionGrowing_mex_modified.cpp`, the MEX completed successfully with this message:

```
mex -compatibleArrayDims RegionGrowing_mex_modified.cpp
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
MEX completed successfully.
```

But unfortunately, an error occurs during running my code, the error is:

[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: But what code is it that you're running? Apparently this code is trying to compile a MEX-file. This error has nothing to do with your MEX-file, you're running some M-file instead. Please read [mre].

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Thank you for your helpful comment. The problem was because of the difference between name in the .m file and the name of the .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

In your source code you need to change this:

```
const int *pSize = mxGetDimensions(prhs[1]);
```

to this instead:

```
const mwSize *pSize = mxGetDimensions(prhs[1]);
```

The way your code is currently, you are asking the compiler to convert a pointer to 64-bit integer into a pointer to 32-bit integer, and it is complaining about that.